# select all from table, without duplicates by 1 column

Tags: sql, select, distinct, clickhouse

I have table (clickhouse) as history:

| id | product_name | count | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | name 1 | 10 | 2022-10-19 |
| 123 | name 1 | 10 | 2022-10-20 |
| 123 | rename 1 | 10 | 2022-10-23 |
| 123 | rename 1 | 12 | 2022-11-19 |
| 222 | name 2 | 50 | 2022-10-23 |
| 222 | name 2 | 50 | 2022-10-24 |
| 222 | name 2 | 52 | 2022-10-25 |

`id` (not unique) it is `product_name` id and product name can change.
Date it is record into table.

I need select all from table where `product_name` or count was changed.

| id | product_name | count | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | name 1 | 10 | 2022-10-19 |
| 123 | rename 1 | 10 | 2022-10-23 |
| 123 | rename 1 | 12 | 2022-11-19 |
| 222 | name 2 | 50 | 2022-10-23 |
| 222 | name 2 | 52 | 2022-10-25 |

I don't have a lot of SQL experience.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
LIMIT 1 BY id, product_name, count
```

That will get you only a single row for each unique combination of (id, product_name, count)

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/limit-by/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the below:

```
SELECT id, product_name, count, date
FROM history
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id, product_name, count
        FROM history
        GROUP BY id, product_name, count
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t
)
ORDER BY id, date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `group by`

I see that you are taking the oldest date so we use `min(date)`

```
SELECT id, product_name, count, min(date)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, product_name, count
order by id
```